# JSON.stringify() isn't properly converting object to a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying a document from Mongo DB using Mongoose:

```
    const dbObj = await User.findOne({ "_id": id});
```

From there, I am attempting to turn that object into a string:

```
    const dbObjStr = JSON.stringify(dbObj);
```

The problem: JSON.stringify isn't properly converting the object to a string, the outcome looks like this:

```
    {"accreditedStatus":3,"count":39}
```

How can I get it to convert to an actual string? Like this:

```
    "{\"accreditedStatus\":3,\"count\":39}"
```

Environment:
Node.js v10.16.0,
NPM 6.10.0,
Mongo DB 4.0.10,
Mongoose ^5.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringify` is working. `dbObjStr` contains a string. The `\"` escape characters you are looking for are not part of the string. You can observe what is going on more clearly by separating your string into an array of single-character strings.

```
console.log(dbObjStr.split(''))
```

If for whatever reason you would like `dbObjStr` to contain the escaped characters, just run `stringify` twice:

```
 const dbObjStr = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(dbObj));
```